# Resizable window with widgets PySide6

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

Im very new with PySide and i need to know "How to do resizable windows". I have a simple code with 3 buttons in differents widgets and layouts. I need to understand the logic.

class resizeTest(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(resizeTest, self).__init__()

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')

    self.widget01 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    self.widget01.setGeometry(15,100,100,100)

    self.okButton = QPushButton(self)
    self.okButton.setText("OK")
    self.cancelButton = QPushButton(self)
    self.cancelButton.setText("Cancel")

    self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.widget01)
    self.hbox.addStretch(3)
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.okButton)
    self.hbox.addWidget(self.cancelButton)

    self.widget02 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    self.widget02.setGeometry(15, 15, 50, 50)
    self.addButton = QPushButton(self)
    self.addButton.setText("add")

    self.vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.widget02)
    self.vbox.addStretch(3)

    self.vbox.addWidget( self.addButton)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `self.setCentralWidget(self.widget01)`. See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework).

Comment: but can i manage the position of the widgets?

Comment: What does that mean? Have you tried what said above?

Comment: this dont scale all widgets proportionally to window, and how i manage the size and position  of the layouts?

Comment: Please read the documentation about [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and also [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html). They are called "layout managers" because they *manage* the layout, so you don't set their geometries, you configure them properly with the layout settings, stretchs, spacings and the widgets' size attributes.